# Parse Youtube Playlist in Windows Metro App

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I tried parsing a Youtube Playlist in windows 8 Metro app using  $.getJSON() but it did not work.but it worked perfectly in other browsers.What am i doing Wrong

Here is the code i tried

```
function start() {
            var playListURL ='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/B2A4E1367126848D?v=2&alt=json&callback=?'
            var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
   $.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
           alert('Done');
            $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
            var title = item.title.$t;
            var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
            var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
            var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
            var url = videoURL + videoID;
            var hot = item.media$credit;
            var thumb = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + videoID + "/hqdefault.jpg";
            $('#title').text(title);
            $('#desc').attr('src', thumb);
             $('.red').attr('title', videoID);

             });
          });

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a feed URL that returns `JSON` and not videos URL which returns `HTML`.

Here is a sameple **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tqWxc/1317/)**

Comment: i Know,I have a valid playlist Url with all the neccesarry Youtube api parameters but its not just working on Windows 8 metro app which am designing with VisualStudio,I think am suppose to parse the Url with Winjs.Xhr but i have no idea on how to do that.Thanks